# What was it like for a coastal village to experience a Viking raid in around the tenth century?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, vikings

Were fishing villages really completely at the mercy of these Vikings, or could they defend them selves? Did villagers have their own weapons? Could they expect any support from a Lord or Land Baron? Why did Vikings put so many buildings to the torch, or is that just Hollywood? Did villagers have any lookouts or advance warning to a Viking raid?

I know monasteries were also raided by Vikings, and the monks were actually tough fighters who fought back! What weapons were used by both sides? Were the monasteries made defensible, and is this reflected in their design?

Comment: Hi Starkers and welcome to History SE! Per the [FAQ], I've removed the book request from your question. Aside from that, it's an interesting question! +1 and welcome to the site!

Comment: @Luke Right oh!

Comment: Just for comparison: Barbary pirate attacks were a serious concern in Catalonia in the Modern Age. Populations reacted by building villages a few kilometers inland. Only about the XVIII century settlements would be build by the sea, which produced an interesting pattern of pairs of villages (one inland, the other upon sea) in some areas (notably Maresme).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Coastal villages were generally unprotected throughout the middle ages and monasteries had little or no protection. Whilst the Vikings were bad some of the time, they were more traders than raiders. 'Viking' is a verb, not a noun. To go "a-viking' meant digging shields out from the bottom of the boat and hanging a figurehead on the prow and taking what you wanted.

Far, far worse were the pirates,raiders, slavers of the late middle ages up to the 17th century. Please see the excellent BBC series [British Slaves on the Barbary Coast](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/british/empire_seapower/white_slaves_01.shtml)

Where I was born in Devon, England the local coastal village church had a plaque remembering one dreadful Sunday when Barbary coast slaves attacked ,killed or enslaved all of the 180 people who lived there in 1358. 
Parts of the Western coast of Spain was partially deserted due to fear of attacks from North Africa and only started to recover at the end of the 19th Century.
[Barbary slave trade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbary_slave_trade)

As an example of a suffering monastery [Lindisfarne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindisfarne) is one of the better known. Graham-Campbell, James; David M. Wilson (2001). "Salt-water bandits" London: Frances Lincoln Ltd.  ISBN 0-7112-1800-5. The [Anglo Saxon chronicles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_Chronicle) are a useful resource with transliteration.

Comment: +1 agreed, Vikings got bad reputation because of paganism, and raids. They had more in their culture than vast barbarism and robbing the coastal villages. They lead various expedition from inner Asia to North America. The "good" christian European nations lead worse enslaving societies in colonial era than Vikings ever.